# directory changes permission when mounted

Tags: permissions, mount, samba

I want to mount a samba sghare to a directory in my home dir. I have created it but mount the share as root. Upon mount, the owner of my dir changes to root and my user doesn't have permission tow rite files on the share... How do I modify my mount line to be able to mount with write permissions? It currently looks like this: `sudo mount -t cifs //IP/share/ /mount/point/ -o rw,username=user,password=pass,domain=domain`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `uid` and `gid` [mount options](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html):

> uid=arg
>
> sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the mounted
> filesystem when the server does not provide ownership information. It
> may be specified as either a username or a numeric uid. When not
> specified, the default is uid 0. The mount.cifs helper must be at
> version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the uid in non-numeric
> form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND PERMISSIONS
> below for more information.
>
> forceuid
>
> instructs the client to ignore any uid provided by the server for
> files and directories and to always assign the owner to be the value
> of the uid= option. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP
> AND PERMISSIONS below for more information.
>
> gid=arg
>
> sets the gid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
> information. It may be specified as either a groupname or a numeric
> gid. When not specified, the default is gid 0. The mount.cifs helper
> must be at version 1.10 or higher to support specifying the gid in
> non-numeric form. See the section on FILE AND DIRECTORY OWNERSHIP AND
> PERMISSIONS below for more information.

Comment: In my case the uid only appleis to new root directory.. but not to the content.. is it possible to set new owner to all the files and directories within a such directory?