# mount cifs folder to linux with all permissions

Tags: linux, cifs

Is there any ability to mount windows share folder to Linux with all permissions:

I want to try this command:

`mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password>,umask=0777 //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /home/backup`

At the moment I could not up any Vbox machine to test it in calm condtitions.

I looked through the http://unix.stackexchange.com and found a lot of unswers: [permissions1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/directory-changes-permission-when-mounted), [permissions2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30268/mount-device-with-r-w-access-to-specific-user), [permissions3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown). But I am not sure about the correctness of my own command.

> Please, advice on this solution. Is the command right or I need to add more parameters to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`umask` did not work for me

So the best way to give all rights to the cifs(samba) folder is to use this command:

> `mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password>,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /home/backup`